# C# client.GetStringAsync(url) stucks

Tags: c#, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

I can't understand what's wrong with my code. I am using https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities to solve cloud flare js. I am trying to get data from page and I am using this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Test1("https://SiteWithCloudFlareProtection.com/");
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
}

async void Test1(string url)
{
    HttpClient HttpClientWithoutCloudFlare = new HttpClient(new ClearanceHandler());
    string json = await HttpClientWithoutCloudFlare.GetStringAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

void Test2(string url)
{
    HttpClient HttpClientWithoutCloudFlare = new HttpClient(new ClearanceHandler());
    string json = HttpClientWithoutCloudFlare.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Without `Thread.Sleep(60000)` `Test1` works perfectly. With `Thread.Sleep(60000)` `Test1` stucks, `Test2` always stucks in command `GetStringAsync(url)`.
`Test1(url).Wait();` stucks too.

Am I missing something?

I just need to solve cloud flare protection and get data from page. I need to do it synchronously.

Comment: modify `Test2` to `async`.  it runs synchronously as you are using `Result` instantly.

Comment: @Venky I need to do it synchronously.

Comment: You are not using `await`. So your code runs synchronously even though you use `async` keyword.

Comment: Are you sure methods stuck? Maybe you should wait for response some time(due to calling synchronously).

Comment: @Venky Test1 is async and use await. Test1(url).Wait(); stucks too.

Comment: @Roma Yes, I waited few minutes, normaly it takes seconds.

Comment: It stucks due to `MessageBox` code. This code blocks all threads. Try to comment `MessageBox` code and se..

Comment: @Venky it's not a reason. I am using debug mode and I see that code stuck in `GetStringAsync()` line. Nothing after it ever run.

Comment: If you want to call them synchronous, did you try with `GetString(..)` synchronous overload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `async` methods in constructors. And you shouldn't block on async code. This may lead to deadlocks. You can read more about this here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Since `Test1` is an `async` method it should return a `Task` and not void:

```
async Task Test1(string url)
{
    HttpClient HttpClientWithoutCloudFlare = new HttpClient(new ClearanceHandler());
    string json = await HttpClientWithoutCloudFlare.GetStringAsync(url);
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

You can then `await` it once the `Form` has been loaded by for example handling the `Shown` event of the `Form`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Shown += async (s, e) =>
    {
        await Test1("https://SiteWithCloudFlareProtection.com/");
        //Thread.Sleep(60000);
    };
}
```

Please refer to the following article for more information about best practices when it comes to asynchronous programming in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx